# Higher Kinded Types - Multiple Kinds

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Given the following Algebraic Data Type of `Maybe`:

```
scala> sealed trait Maybe[A]
defined trait Maybe

// "Nada" in Spanish means "nothing"
scala> case object Nada extends Maybe[Nothing]
defined object Nada

scala> case class Just[A](x: A) extends Maybe[A]
defined class Just
```

Then, I defined a method, `success`, that takes a type, `A`, and a higher-kinded type, `M[A]`.

```
scala> def success[A, M[A]](x: A): M[A] = ???
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
success: [A, M[A]](x: A)M[A]
```

I can define a `Functor`:

```
scala> case class Functor[A](x: A)
defined class Functor
```

Then, I can apply it to `success`:

```
scala> success[Int, Functor](5)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

However, I can't apply a higher-kinded type that requires **2 type parameters**.

```
scala> success[Int, Either]
<console>:12: error: Either takes two type parameters, expected: one
       success[Int, Either]
                    ^
```

Is it possible for me to modify `success` to accept any higher-kinded type, i.e. `1 ... N` kinds?

Comment: Not exactly, but you can use a [type lambda](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/07/11/roll-your-own-scala/) to partially apply the either type constructor.

Comment: You need a type-level lambda like `success[Int, ({type λ[α] = Either[ErrorType, α]})#λ]`